# Pentaho/Kettle - Split Fields into two columns

Tags: split, multiple-columns, etl, pentaho, kettle

im currently having trouble to split a column in pentaho that has the item ID at the begining. The main idea is to split the current column into "ItemID" and "ItemName" by "space" delimiter. I split the column with the space delimiter and get the "ItemID" correctly, but i can't get the "ItemName" completly.

[image: Original column and the way that must be splited]

In the resulting columns, "ItemID" is fine, but "ItemName" only gets the first part of the name. I have tried to change the lenght or Trim type, but i see no changes.

[image: Result]

I would really appreciate some help, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by splitting in several strings the "ItemName", and then concatenating all together. For last the extra columns were deleted.

[image: Spliting]

Answer (score 1):

The best options are to either:

- use a regex evaluation
- Use replace in strings

In Regex evaluation you can create new fields for capture groups, whereas in Replace in string you can create new fields with the replace values. In either case you can use the regex `([^ ]*) (.*)`. The first group captures everything up to the first space, the second captures the rest.